# How to display totals per user after sign in - database with 25,000 users - millions of rows?

Tags: mysql, database

I'm dealing with a database for about 25,000 users who add about 6 rows on average every day (employees keeping logs for work orders). Basically the database grows indefinite and contains millions of rows (to divide among these 25,000 users).

After a user logs in, I would like the system to display some of their totals such as miles driven in truck number xyz for their entire work career, total time worked on order item xyz and so on. Basically, every time a user logs in, these totals need to be present instantly. In addition, once a user adds a row for a work order, the totals need to reflect this change instantly.

Is it advised to build a totals table per user that gets updated with every entry. Or should I just query the database and have it calculate the total on the fly each time a user logs in (no total tables). Would that however create a bottleneck if users log in every second and the database needs to spit out a total based on millions of rows? How does google do it? :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might find that a simple query is fast enough with an appropiate index (e.g. index `user_id`). This should reduce the number of rows that need to be scanned.

But if this is not fast enough, you could calculate the result for all users overnight, and cache this result in another table. You can then do the following:

- Get the total up to the last cache update directly from the cache table.
- Get the total since the last cache update from the main table.
- Add these two numbers to get the overall total.

Another option is to use [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/triggers.html) to keep the pre-calculated result accurate, even when rows are inserted, updated or deleted.

Comment: @ Mark I like the idea about the cache, however, after a user adds a row, the totals need to reflect the addition instantly after refresh. Thank you for replying!

Comment: @Mark I like the idea about triggers...however no clue what they are. I will have to research. The solution sounds good. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than do a join a the million row table, i think you can create a summary table.
it can be populated running a cron at night for example.

Comment: but then the totals would not reflect instant change, correct?

Comment: The totals would be fine if you used write triggers to update the summary table.

Comment: @glowcoder What are write triggers?? I'll have to research this! Thx

Comment: @flukyspore you can also update the summary table as you add more changes

Comment: @lbu true... I think I'll research the difference between what some people mention as "triggers"...

Answer (score 0):

If you want it "instant", then stay away from keeping the totals in tables as then you have to worry about updating them through some process every time the underlying data changes.

As long as your indexes are good, and you have some decent hardware then I don't see a problem with querying for these totals every time.

As far as Google, they have lots and lots of servers, basically keep their entire index in RAM, and have virtually unlimited computing power.

Comment: Ok, no total tables. Hardware and keys should not be a problem. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

If you actually find that after indexing your tables the search/update is too slow for your liking, consider splitting the logs table into several. Depending on your design and interest in speed up it could be spliced multiple ways:

```
log_truck_miles (driver, truck_id, miles)
log_work_times (worker, job_id, minutes) ...etc.
```

Another way you could split is quantize worker IDs -- log entries for user_id below 5,000 go into table `log_0_5`. 5,000 to 10,000 go to `log_5_10`

Comment: Never thought about such an approach. It might be necessary in the future I suppose as the database keeps growing to no end. I appreciate the answer!

Comment: I've never had to do this myself, even for tables with near 2 million rows (mysql) but it's something to keep in mind.